# Woocommerce fancybox gallery on products

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, fancybox

I'm using `fancybox` plugin as a `lightbox` plugin. On my `woocommerce` product page I have created a link that should open a gallery associated with each product (the code below is in content-product.php inside the loop so it works fine).

```
global $product;
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

        <div class="product_quick_view">
            <?php $first_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_ids[0], 'full'); ?>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group<?php echo $product->id; ?>" href="<?php echo $first_image[0]; ?>"><?php echo esc_html('Quick view', 'theme'); ?></a>
            <div class="hidden_gallery">
            <?php foreach($attachment_ids as $image_id){
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' );
                echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="group'.$product->id.'" href="'.$image_url[0].'">'.wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'full' ).'</a>';
            }; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Which outputs this

```
<div class="product_quick_view">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group3709" href="../uploads/2014/09/image1.jpg">Quick view</a>
    <div class="hidden_gallery">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group3709" href="../uploads/2014/09/image1.jpg">
        <img width="552" height="820" src="../uploads/2014/09/image1.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="image1">
        </a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group3709" href="../uploads/2014/09/image2.jpg">
        <img width="552" height="820" src="../uploads/2014/09/image2.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="image2">
        </a>                
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.hidden_gallery` class will make the images in that div not visible. This should make it so that the `fancybox` will go through all the images in the same `rel` attribute.

But for some reason, it's not doing that. When I click the 'Quick view' link, I get the image that is attached to that link, but no other images (and they are in the DOM).

Is this because the fancybox jQuery fired before the images could be loaded with the woocommerce? I have it inside the `$(document).ready()` environment, should I wrap it inside the `.load()` environment or use the `.imagesLoaded` plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. Apparently fancybox is not working, and is generally having issues with woocommerce, so I used the one that comes with woocommerce.

Just add this

```
<a itemprop="image" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]<?php echo $product->id;?>" href="...
```

This will group them and you'll use woocommerce's own fancybox that works.

Comment: How do I implement this on the checkout page? I add a link using the `itemprop="image"` and `data-rel="prettyPhoto"` attributes but it never loads lightbox. I have tried to include it into functions.php with some code found on the web, but it fails to display inside the lightbox.

Comment: Did you put `data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]`? I think the product-gallery needs to be there for it to work, I'm not 100% sure, but try it. Also check to see if the prettyPhoto javascript code is loaded (in inspector go to Sources tab, and in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets see if it's there).